# Avoid re-writing FOR loop for special cases

Tags: python, for-loop, tqdm

All my python scripts take in a bool argument called `debug`, which if True, prints out a load of stuff and does `for` loop progress bar using `tqdm` as shown below

```
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(1000)):
     ## rest of the calculation
```

However, I would like to disable the `tqdm` progress bar when debug is false and I am not sure how to do this other than rewriting the `for` loop again without `tqdm` (for debug=False case). Any suggestions on how to do this more elegantly are much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define `tqdm` conditionally:

```
if debug:
    from tqdm import tqdm
else:
    def tqdm(x):  # Noop version when not in debug mode
        return x

    # Alternative version that's slightly less clear,
    # but probably slightly more performant, due to using built-in:
    tqdm = iter  # Explicitly make it convert the input to an iterator, but do nothing else
```

That makes `tqdm` a no-op when not in debug mode, so your original `for` loop still works without modification or duplication.